# OPC UA block write of a sensor data to a tag

Tags: protocols, plc, opc-ua, industrial

Can OPC-UA write data to a tag in blocks / chunks? Let's say I have a sensor/UA client that samples at 100Hz and needs to send those data to a UA server, I have an OPC UA tag on that server to take in that sensor's data. Can I have a "blocked" write, to write 100 samples all together in one transaction to that tag every second? Each sample has a source timestamp. So for offline application it does not matter how the data were sent.

Currently, I transmit the samples one by one, therefore 100 write transactions for 1 second of data, is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Unless that server is configured to store history for that tag then whether you write 100 values at once (which yes, is possible) or 100 values in a row to the same tag the end result is the same - the tag's value attribute will be the last value of the 100.

Maybe you should consider configuring the tag in that server to be an array and then writing an array of values to it?

Comment: It is good to know this is possible! Do you have an example, or a reference, for writing 100 values at once to a tag? To clarify a bit, if I write 100 values at once to a tag in one transaction, it is not just the software process, the number of packets transmitted will also be reduced, hence also improve the network efficiency, correct?

Comment: I don't know what language or stack you are using, but the OPC UA Write service is defined in such a manner that it accepts multiple writes per call. It should be trivial.

Comment: I am using python-opcua. On the client side, I just do for example:
v = objects.add_variable(3, 'MyROVariable', 6)
v.set_value(4) 
This will set one value to one tag. But how to bundle 100 together?
https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/blob/858274721766907148b527916e97446dbbf6af6d/tests/tests_client.py

Comment: Maybe the `set_values` method on the `Client` object: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/blob/858274721766907148b527916e97446dbbf6af6d/opcua/client/client.py#L666-L674